# How to display the comment form of a node in a popup?

Tags: comments, javascript

How can I display the comment form in a popup. I want the functionality when I click on the link "add new comment" on a node, the comment form should appear in a popup window.

Any one who have some idea?

Comment: You mean real popup, a window from your browser or a modal box, like dialog from jQuery ?

Comment: I mean a dialog from JQuery.

Comment: Have you tried colorbox or fancybox modules? I have tried those with forms. It may work with comments also.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Dialog API](http://drupal.org/project/dialog) for Drupal 6, and Drupal 7 (although only the development snapshot for Drupal 7 is visible in the project page). This module contains sub-module Dialog Comment.

For Drupal 7, as I can see, there are some problems with modules for popup dialogues.

Comment: Is there any jquery plugin to which I pass the form id and then it shows that form in a popup?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for it I can propose you a 'sexy' solution.

```
$(function(){
  var comments = elem = $('#comments'); // I get the element comments
  if(comments.size() > 0) { // I check if is exist
    // Here I remplace the form with a link
    var link = elem.replaceWith('<a href="#comments">'+ Drupal.t("Comment my node") +'</a>');
    // For the new link I give him a OnClick event.
    link.clik(function(){
      // Here I just hide the submit button, you can hide other buttons as well
      $('input[type=submit]', comments).css('display', 'none');
      // Here the dialog from jQuery UI you can change is as well
      comments.dialog({
        buttons: {
          "Comment": function() {
              $('form', comments).submit();
          },
          "Cancel": function() {
              $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        },
        modal: true,
        height: 245,
        width: 475,
        title: title,
        open: function() {
        },
        close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
        },
        resizable: false,
      });
    });
  }
});
```

You've to include this code in the header or footer of your theme (better if you can check before if you're on one page with comments or not. And be sure that jQuery UI Dialog is also loaded with [drupal_add_library](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7).

P.S. I didn't try the code, so maybe you'll find some bugs, but the main idea is there.

Comment: How should I include the jQuery UI Dialog? Is it drupal_add_library('jQuery UI Dialog')?

Comment: Like this ´ drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.dialog');´

Comment: I have copied your js code to popup.js file. Then In the module file and in the form_alter function I added ´ drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.dialog'); drupal_add_js('popup.js'); Is it fine? As it did not work for me.

Comment: Put your popup.js into your theme folder. After in your template.php add `drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/popup.js'); drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.dialog');`

Comment: My default theme is bartik. I put the popup.js file in the bartik folder and then I added those two lines at the end of the template.php file. I replace the path_to_path() with themes/bartik. But still it does not work.

Comment: `drupal_add_js()` can be used with a module too. The path must be relative to the Drupal root directory, which means you need to use `drupal_get_path()`.

Comment: I have used drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik') . '/popup.js'); But it did not work. Where should I use it?

Comment: @yvan I have included this in my module file and there it works fine. The   Comment my node link appear on the node page but when I click on it nothing happens.

Comment: It's my fault, I made a mistake in `link.clik` it must be `link.click` :)

Answer (score 1):

[Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) has a nice modal functionality that is easy to use, and doesn't need you to manually add any depended JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a fancy non-technical way use Beauty Tips module.

if you need help here is a good video on this topic.

http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-enhanced-with-beauty-tips-module