# Comment Form in Popup

Tags: ajax, javascript

I want hide comment form on node pages but show it in popup when a comment link is clicked.If the user is not logged in, the comment link should display login form. Should i do it inside preprocess function?i am using comment form in panel and hook_page_alter is showing rendered output of the comment form when i dsm it...any tips or help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display the comment form of a node in a popup?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-display-the-comment-form-of-a-node-in-a-popup)

Comment: Well no clear-cut solution over there and also i need to display login form in popup if the user isnt logged in..so my question is a bit different